# Changing server.maxPayloadBytes on AWS Elasticsearch Service

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

So I have a ES cluster hosted through AWS where documnets are mostly of dynamic JSON without fixed mapping.

When I try to the do the "Create index pattern" on Kibana,
it errors out with:

`Error Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576`

So I need to either increase `server.maxPayloadBytes` on `kibana.yml` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html)

or figure out another way.

To increase `server.maxPayloadBytes` on `kibana.yml`, I have to edit it directly but not sure how to do that.
I have VPC endpoint for the cluster but I couldn't ssh into it.

---

I am running

```
Elasticsearch version: 6.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talked to DevOps, apprently changing `server.maxPayloadBytes` on AWS Elasticsearch Service is not possible since AWS (as of now) does not allow it